Filtering reference rows from same table
I trying to create slice that filter references from the same table(I need to get other rows in person table as family members). I tired REF_ROWS but it is not yes/no result. I tryed simple [_THISROW].[Row ID]=[Row ID] but no results. Only results gave me this: ANY(Persons[id_relative])=[Row ID] - but it return only one,random row.
Perhapse someone of you had same problem?
Update:

Im trying get all references based on that field and display that in seperate partial view connected to dashboard view
I think I should filter it by Row ID which is key in this table


Please provide a markdown example of a table and explain what you are trying to filter.

Thank you for response, I made update in post description. Does it tell you anything?

If I wish to filter I usually use the filter method of arrays.
